# php изменение контента одной страницы с другой

Tags: php

Заранее извиняюсь за вопрос, я абсолютно не умею в пхп и желания разбираться ради такой мелочи нет. Мне нужно чтобы при вводе числа в форму на одной странице оно переносилось в div на другой странице. Нужно максимально простое решение, неважно какое по объему.

Числа 3585 и 960 нужно менять.

```
<div id="dolg">3585</div> <div id="vernyl">960</div>
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Возможное решение: изменять число в txt файле (на html страницу помещу его через js, но если поможете и выводить его через php будет шикарно)

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 2**

Я понял что слишком просто не будет, поэтому извините за трату вашего времени, придется разбираться с php.

Comment: Да тут дело не в РНР. В форме указываейте скрипт нужной страницы - и передавайте число туда

Comment: @DNS мне нужно чтобы изменения остались навсегда, не думаю что с помощью js такое реализуемо

Comment: Прошу уточнить задачу. В простейшем случае Вы делаете форму с вводом числа и указываете `action` для его обработки. В этом `action` можно делать с числом что угодно. В любых временнЫх рамках

Comment: Есть поле, я ввожу в него число допустим 1000, жму ок, после этого на другой странице в определенном div с определенным id число которое было меняется на 1000 навсегда.

Comment: Другая страница этого сайта? Число берется из БД или откуда?

Comment: @DNS другая страница этого сайта. Число изначально просто написано на html странице, как я уже сказал в теге div с определенным id, но при желании хотелось бы менять его не открывая html, а просто вводя в число в поле на созданной для этого странице (Что-то типа админки)

Comment: Ну если число в html, то это текстовый файл. Заменить число навсегда - значит переписать файл. Это не супер-просто... Если выделить это число как отдельный файл или запись в БД - то легче - один скрипт меняет, другой выводит

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - вывести число в INI файл (если уж совсем нет БД)

> the_value = 3585

Из РНР [парсите](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php) этот файл

При формировании HTML выводите считанное значение

```
<div id="dolg"><?=$the_value?></div>
```

При обновлении числа перезаписываете файл INI c новым числом.

Но я бы советовал БД

Comment: Можно ещё попробовать в куки браузера записывать. Чтобы `навсегда`.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics куки - это `навсегда` только в одном браузере. И то если куки вечные

Answer (score 2):

Допустим есть форма на странице `form.html`:

```
<form>
    <input name="vernul" value="960" />
    <input type="submit" formaction="handler.php" formmethod="get"
           value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

В скрипте обработчике `handler.php` читаем переменную `$_GET['vernul']` и формируем `<div>`:

```
<?php
   $dolg = 3585;
   if(! isset($_GET['vernul'])) die('Expected vernul.');
   if(! is_numeric($_GET['vernul'])) die('vernul is not a number.');
   $vernul = intval($_GET['vernul']);
   $output = '<div id="dolg">' . ($dolg - $vernul) . '</div>';
   $output .= '<div id="vernul">' . $vernul . '</div>';
   echo $output;
?>
```

Это пример. Запись и чтение базы данных, думаю, приводить смысла нет.

Comment: Но ведь это не `навсегда`